# Qual é a diferença entre redirecionamento 301 e 302?

Tags: http, seo, redirecionamento, redirecionamento-de-url

Gostaria de saber qual é a diferença entre esses dois tipos de código de redirecionamento: o 301 e o 302.

Percebi que eles são chamados no Webmaster Tools do Google de *Redirecionamento permanente* e *Redirecionamento temporário*, respectivamente o `301` e o `302`.

**Perguntas:**

- Mas qual é a diferença? Importa tanto assim redirecionar usando um ou outro?
- Por exemplo, em um redirecionamento quando o usuário faz um login, eu deveria utilizar `301` ou `302`?
- O que seria esse *"permanente"*? Eu não entendi muito bem. Pareceu-me estar relacionado a uma url que agora sempre será redirecionada para outra.

Comment: [link](https://marketeiro.wordpress.com/2009/11/07/redirecionamento-301-e-302-qual-a-diferenca/)

Comment: Isso soa muito mais sendo uma decisão de SEO.
Links uteis: https://seo-hacker.com/301-302-redirect-affect-seo/
http://www.stepforth.com/blog/2008/redirects-permanent-301-vs-temporary-302/

Comment: Quer dizer que: *302 é o deslocamento do funcionário do trabalho pra casa, e 301 é quando o funcionário é demitido*?

Comment: A analogia pode ser usada :P 
`302` o funcionário não esta mais no serviço, esta em casa, o chefe precisa conversar com o funcionário... peça para a atendente (no caso os motores de busca do google) que faca uma ligação para a casa do funcionário.
`301` o funcionário não esta mais no serviço, foi demitido, o chefe precisa falar com o funcionário.... mas o funcionário já se matou e não pode mais ser contactado :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quando a página pretendida não se encontra no local esperado podes usar 301 (para uma mudança permanente) e 302 (para uma mudança temporária).

Redirecionamentos de login ou fruto de navegação da página são outra coisa, há um [post no SOen interessante](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15302297/2256325). Basicamente se tentar aceder uma página interna sem ter feito login, deve dar 4xx.

Na [especificação dos estados HTTP](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) diz (tradução livre):

**301** - mudança permanente, links e acessos futuros devem usar a nova url.

> The requested resource has been assigned a new permanent URI and any future references to this resource SHOULD use one of the returned URIs.

**302** - encontrado, mas temporariamente disponível noutro url, o cliente deve continuar a usar o url original para aceder a este conteúdo/página.

> The requested resource resides temporarily under a different URI. Since the redirection might be altered on occasion, the client SHOULD continue to use the Request-URI for future requests.

Comment: O redirecionamento de login que quis dizer é aqueles redirecionamentos que fazemos na unha quando o usuário acaba de logar. Por exemplo, ele acabou de logar, agora vou redirecionar ela para página "logged/home". Esse seria 301 ou 302?

Comment: @WallaceMaxters depende do url. O caso mais normal é o redirect ser feito para quem não tem acesso. Um redirect depois do login feito deve dar um 200 pois vai para uma nova página certo? isso é navegação.

Comment: Sem querer te incomodar demais: No caso de um usuário já logado que tenta acessar a página "login", porém eu quero "jogar ele" para uma página de quem já está logado (quando ele tentar acessar a página "login"), eu usaria 301?

Comment: @WallaceMaxters não sou expert de HTTP mas para mim isso deve dar um primeiro `200`, pois a página em causa existe e está disponível, e depois faz-se um redirect de navegação para outra página pois o login já está feito; e isso dá novo `200` na nova página caso ela esteja online.

Answer (score 5):

Permanente quer dizer que o endereço antigo "não existe mais" e este novo é o "oficial". Temporário quer dizer que em algum momento o endereço antigo voltará a funcionar.

Pense numa pagina no estilo "Em Manutenção", o redirecionamento para ela é do tipo temporário, pois uma hora a manutenção terminará.

Já digamos que a empresa mudou de nome, e o site redireciona para um novo domínio com o novo nome da empresa, o redirecionamento é permanente, o domínio antigo pode até deixar de existir em algum momento.

A aplicação é bem flexível, são só exemplos, a ideia é informar ao browser (e sites de pesquisa como o Google) como analisar o redirecionamento.

Em muitos casos, realmente, tanto faz.