# Identificação de SSL pelo Google

Tags: htaccess, google

Ontem fiz a migração do website para outro provedor e ganhei um certificado SSL, ao qual já foi aplicado. Gostaria de saber se o Google irá identificar automaticamente que agora o site é seguro (https), pois na busca, o resultado aparece como "http".

Configurei o .htaccess para redirecionar qualquer requisição para a página segura:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para o Google, assim como outros buscadores detectarem a mudança é necessário usar o [**Redirecionamento permanente**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/178067/3635), que no caso é o código 301 para HTTP, é possivel aplicar ele via `.htaccess` usando a flag `R=301` (a flag `L` é apenas para evitar conflitos com outros `RewriteRules`), também não tenho certeza, mas acho que a flag `QSA` seja necessário se tiver alguma página que faz o uso de querystring.

Ainda sim é **importante** notar que o Google não reindexa todas as páginas de uma vez, isto pode levar semanas.

O .htaccess deve ficar assim:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,L]
```

Relacionado:

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/202079/3635
- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/207031/3635
- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/188963/3635

Comment: o problema exatamente não está no redirecionamento dos arquivos, isso está funcionando corretamente. a pergunta em questão é referente à busca no google, que não aparece como página segura (https)

Comment: @JulyanoFelipe foi o que eu disse, precisa do R=301, o google não reindexa em segundos, ele pode levar semanas para reindexar ;)

Comment: Então eu adicionando a flag R=301 fará com que o Google identifique como seguro?

Comment: O Google vai reindexar, com o HTTPs ao invés de HTTP nas páginas de busca, isso não quer dizer que o site é "seguro" para o Google, só quer dizer que usa o protocolo "HTTPS" ;) ... De qualquer forma como eu disse amigo, isto pode levar semanas, eu editei a resposta para ficar melhor o entendimento.